# analyzing the GSon project with SonarQube produces 0.0% test coverage

Tags: github, sonarqube, gson

I'm trying to analyze the official `GSon` project downloaded from GitHub using `SonarQube` running on `Docker` even though all the tests are run successfully and the analysis is complete it show 0.0% test coverage in the end.

[image]

this is the command I'm using to start the analysis:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=gson_resurrection -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=840db6fded6390e6dbf1a09b757e01be386c6781
```

and this is the final output:
[image]

Comment: You probably have to also configure JaCoCo, as for example described in [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage).

Comment: thx, I've added the `Jacoco` `dependency` and `plugin` to each pom.xml in the project. But how did you know I should add it?

Comment: I googled for SonarQube Maven code coverage, and also remembered that in a Maven project I worked on JaCoCo was used in combination with SonarQube.